# Can't get access to file on localhost under Windows

Tags: windows, git, apache, github, yii

Periodically after branch downloading from github Yii shows such an issue:

```
copy(Z:\home\localhost\www\insur\insurance\assets\c75d288a\css\_notes\dwsync.xml) [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

(/_notes/dwsync.xml - is a file created by DreamWeaver automatically for developer's notes).
I can't figure out following:

1. Why Yii tries to implement copy($path,$dst.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);  for that file (it's here: **[site_root]\yii\framework\utils\CFileHelper.php(130)**)?
2. Why an access error is possible on Windows localhost?
3. What exactly is an error source - Windows, Apache or Yii (or maybe DW)?
4. What is solution?

So a real Guru needed!
I believe that here is one!

Answer (score 1):

1. Generally Yii [Assets Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager) will try to publish (or republish) copies of diffirent resources (img, css, js, ..etc) used by your app (made by you or nativly in the framework, e.g Gii module stuff)
2. An access error can happen in localhost if you didn't set needed permission to web-server process. But in this exact case i think the web-server can not find the folder from the begining.
3. It is a joint crime between Yii & Apache. Yii `CAssestsManager` expects an **assets** folder, Apache can't find it and complains
4. Proposed **Solution:**

Make sure you have a folder named **assets** in your App Root and make sure it's **writable** by the web server process!!

To understand more about Yii Assests check this [wiki-post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/)

Comment: Thank you, Nimir! But here is one question which is unclear for me. I just don't know how to check if an access folder is writable for web process. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: well, since you are using localhsot for developing i recommend setting folder permission to be writable for all process to avoid the unnecessary headache of access write, check this: http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm Ofcouse things should not be like this in deployment.